# Get EarthEngine Image from URL to geoTIFF

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-earth-engine

I haven't been able to ascertain if there is a way to load a geoTIFF into an `ee.Image`. I am quite certain that it is possible to do that in some way using a combination of AppEngine and EarthEngine going this route:  `load geoTIFF -> ee.Array + metadata -> ee.Image`.
Or is it a matter of choosing some 3rd party python lib that allows this, pull the data with urllib, interpret that using the lib and create an ee.Array from that?

(by ee.Array I more or less mean an array in an earth-engine context. Not a concrete data type)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly load a GeoTIFF from a URL through a script, but you can upload a GeoTIFF using the earthengine command line tool.

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/command_line

The only other option might be to go through an ee.Blob(), however there's no way to convert that directly into an Array or an Image, and no way to decode a GeoTIFF there.